# SSLCertVerificationError & URLError

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate

I deployed a web app to the google app engine in the past and it works fine. I recently had to make some changes to the python code, it runs fine locally and upon deploying it again, some charts don't show up. (https://leo-satellite-overview.nw.r.appspot.com/).

Checking the Error Reporting: It's showing two errors

1. SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: Hostname mismatch, certificate is not valid for 'www.celestrak.org'. (_ssl.c:1129)
2. URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: Hostname mismatch, certificate is not valid for 'www.celestrak.org'. (_ssl.c:1129).

Please see details of the errors [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MImHCT0ySpMl6dqpwMk-xo0KFpIn2SsQ/view?usp=sharing)

See the code that returns the two charts

`@app.callback(

```
Output('satellite map', 'figure'),

Output('altitude chart', 'figure'),

Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals'),

Input('satellites dropdown', 'value'))
```

def plot_map(n, satellite_name):

```
try:

    lon_list = []

    lat_list = []

    alt_list = []

    obj_name_list = []
    
    time_list = []

    time = datetime.now()

    orb = Orbital(satellite_name)

    lon, lat = orb.get_lonlatalt(time)[0], orb.get_lonlatalt(time)[1]

    lon_list.append(lon)

    lat_list.append(lat)

    obj_name_list.append(satellite_name)
    
    for i in range(121):
        
        time_list.append(time-timedelta(minutes = i))
    
    for i in time_list:
        
        alt_list.append(orb.get_lonlatalt(i)[2])

    df_4 = pd.DataFrame({'ObjectName': obj_name_list, 'Latitude': lat_list, 'Longitude': lon_list})
    
    df_5 = pd.DataFrame({'TimeStamp': time_list, 'Altitude': alt_list})

    lon_list.clear()

    lat_list.clear()

    alt_list.clear()
    
    time_list.clear()
    
    obj_name_list.clear()

    df_4_copy = df_4.copy()
    
    df_5_copy = df_5.copy()

    fig =go.Figure(go.Scattermapbox(

        lat = df_4_copy['Latitude'], lon = df_4_copy['Longitude'], marker = {'size': 20, 'symbol':'rocket'},

        hovertext = df_4_copy['ObjectName'],


    )
                  )

    fig.update_layout(

    mapbox = {'accesstoken':api_token,

             'style': 'light', 'zoom': 0,

             },

    margin = dict(l = 0, r =0, t = 0, b = 0),

    height = 800, hovermode = 'closest')
    
    fig2 = go.Figure(go.Scatter(x = df_5_copy['TimeStamp'], y = df_5_copy['Altitude']))
    
    fig2.update_layout(margin = dict(l = 20, r = 20, t = 20, b = 20),
                      
                      plot_bgcolor = 'rgb(255,255,255)', paper_bgcolor = 'rgb(255,255,255)',
                      
                      height = 800, title = {'text': 'Altitude Trend of' + ' ' + str(satellite_name) + ' ' + 'in near real time', 'x':0.5, 'y':0.98}, 
                      
                      ).update_yaxes(gridcolor = 'rgb(243,243,243)', title ='Altitude (km)').update_xaxes(title = 'Timestamp', linecolor = 'rgb(243,243,243)')
    
    
    
    return fig, fig2

except NotImplementedError:
    
    pass`
```

The full code is here: https://github.com/0ladayo/Low-Earth-Orbit-Satellites-Project/blob/master/main.py

I have tried some suggested solutions on the web to no avail.

Can anyone help

Thank you.

Comment: So far the issue seems not to be your code at all but the `pyorbital.orbital` library which is the one reaching the endpoint `www.celestrak.org` https://github.com/pytroll/pyorbital/search?q=celestrak

Comment: I think I agree with you. I also noticed their recent commit on the tlefile.py where the data needed is pulled from was to update the CelesTrak URLs from .com to .org [link](https://github.com/pytroll/pyorbital/commit/e7aea0b866b37c23810441dabbd3179b4df9e0fa#:~:text=TLE_URLS%20%3D%20(%27http%3A//www.celestrak,org/NORAD/elements/engineering.txt%27))

Comment: I should also add that when I load the URLs on the browser, I am prompted with 'your connection is not private and this NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Comment: @Oladayo I have seen the issue has been resolved in [Github](https://github.com/pytroll/pyorbital/commit/e7aea0b866b37c23810441dabbd3179b4df9e0fa#:~:text=TLE_URLS%20%3D%20(%27http%3A//www.celestrak,org/NORAD/elements/engineering.txt%27)). Can you post your answer?

Comment: @SandeepVokkareni Yes, the issue has been resolved. 

This is what happened.

Pyorbital library pulls data from CelesTrak. CelesTrak recently migrated its domain from .com to .org.

The endpoints (URLs) used by Pyorbital were updated but with HTTP protocol leading to an insecure website with invalid certificates.

The endpoints (URLs) needed to use HTTPS protocol without the need for 'www.' in the endpoints.

discussion in this [link](https://github.com/pytroll/pyorbital/commit/e7aea0b866b37c23810441dabbd3179b4df9e0fa)

That has been done and the update has just been released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the issue was with the [`pyorbital`](https://github.com/pytroll/pyorbital) library which was using the wrong endpoints making the SSL issue appear.

For now there is already a [fix](https://github.com/pytroll/pyorbital/commit/e7aea0b866b37c23810441dabbd3179b4df9e0fa) and now it is [released](https://github.com/pytroll/pyorbital/releases/tag/v1.7.3).

This is the reason the app was failing when retrieving data.

Comment: You are absolutely right. The fix has been released just now. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

1. Based on the comments, OP doesn't own the domain which means OP is not responsible for getting a multi-domain SSL or using the SSL provided by google cloud. I am striking out the previous answer.
2. It seems like OP's code is attempting to load urls whose domain is `https://celestrak.org` but the SSL for that domain is actually for `https://celestrak.com`. But can't figure it out yet.

1. Your domain is a ```.org``` i.e. ```http://celestrak.org/``` but the certificate was issued to a ```.com``` i.e. ```http://celestrak.com/```. I believe you'll need a multi-domain certificate else you should change the certificate to your domain which ends in ```.org```

2. Another option is to use the Google Cloud issued SSL certificate i.e. login to `console.cloud.google.com`, select your project, then navigate `App Engine > Settings > Custom Domains`, select your custom domain and click the `Enable Managed Security`.

Note: You won't get the mismatched certificate error in Firefox. Firefox simply changes your site to `http`

Comment: Hi, I discovered that the Celestrack web address was recently changed from .com to .org. I am using the default address google cloud provided and not a custom domain (can't register for Google Domains due to my Location) and there are no SSL certificates associated with the project. So pls can you clarify the multi-domain certificate you talked about. Thank you

Comment: I don't believe the SSL certificate mismatch is the cause of the error when you visit the ```.appspot``` url of your project. Check your logs again or use your browser's web developer tool to see what is happening on those pages where some charts don't show up

Comment: I checked the logs again and it's the same errors that it is raising. I am thinking to try this on a new project on GCP

Comment: Is the code for the chart that is failing making a call to ```https://celestrak.org/```?  Can you add the code for any of the charts that are failing? What does your browser console show (any errors or warning)?

Comment: The code uses the Pyorbital library to obtain the data. The initial data passed to the Pyorbital library was obtained from `https://celestrak.org/`. It works fine in the local environment but just gae. The browser console shows two errors. The errors logs are shown here [link](https://cloudlogging.app.goo.gl/xbG1Li3DDdimp8PM6) Thanks

Comment: @Oladayo nobody will be able to see those logs. that is a direct link to your project ... Please edit your question or add these logs there as text

Comment: As @FerreginaPelona said, nobody can see your logs. What is more important is the code that draws the chart that is not being displayed correctly. If that code is making calls to ```https://celestrak.org/```, then that might lead to a failure because of the certificate mismatch. I don't know this for sure; can only know by looking at your code. It might work on your local environment because your local environment is not an exact replica of production.

Comment: @NoCommandLine  I have added the details of the two errors in a text file [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MImHCT0ySpMl6dqpwMk-xo0KFpIn2SsQ/view)

Comment: @Oladayo we are running in circles. What you share is basically the error messages you've already shared in the question. What NoCommandLine is asking and basically all the SO community expects is a code snippet of how you're calling the external endpoint. How are we supposed to give insight on something we don't know like the code?

Comment: @FerreginaPelona so sorry. I have updated the question to include the code snippet that returns the two charts that are missing and a link to the full code

Comment: What's version of Python do you have on your local machine?

Comment: 3.8.13. I also have to say that when I run it on google cloud shell before deploying it, it works fine also

Comment: Your ```app.yaml``` file has ```python3.9```. Change it to ```Python3.8``` and run again. Could be that there's a difference between SSL behavior on both versions

Comment: still the same outcome after I changed the runtime to Python 3.8

Comment: I've run out of debugging options. If I come up with something, I'll post. Maybe someone else will be able to help.